# Заполнить форму, отослать данные, а потом вернуть без перезагрузки результат

Tags: ajax, perl

Подскажите, очень срочно надо разобраться, как заполнять форму, отсылать данные  perl-скрипту, а потом вовзращать без перезагрузки результат на страницу
Пока такой простой пример

```
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){                            // по завершению загрузки страницы
        $('#myform').submit(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "1.html",
                success: function(data){
                    $(".result").html(data);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
   </script>
   </head>
  <body>
 <form id="myform" method="get" action="1.pl">
    <input type="text" name="surname" id="username">
    <input id="submit_button" type="submit" value="Отправить">
 </form>
<div class="result">

</div>
```

</body>
   </html>

И perl-обработчик

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use CGI;
use Fcntl;
$q = CGI->new;
my $f = $q->param("surname") . "Пенза!";
return $f;
```

По нажатию на кнопку возвращается код страницы и получается на странице еще одно поле для ввода данных и кнопка.

Comment: Такое ощущение, что и этот код написан наугад... Долго разбирать все плюхи, но первый же вопрос (другие будут если вы продемонстрируете понимание того, что пишете): как вы думаете, на какой URL отправляется форма при нажатии на "Отправить"?

Answer (score 1):

Вот так мог бы выглядеть перловый обработчик, если бы до него доходило:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use utf8;
use CGI::Carp qw/fatalsToBrowser/;

my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $surnanme = $cgi->param('surname').'Пенза!';

print "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8\n\n$surname";
```

Сравните и попробуйте перечислить свои ошибки.